# 'Can't reopen the table <temporary table>' on trying to delete the duplicate rows from mysql

Tags: mysql

The following query throws error as

> can't reopen the table

```
DELETE FROM _temptable
WHERE RowNo > 
(
    SELECT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT MIN(RowNo) 
    FROM _temptable
    WHERE Status= 'Deleted'
    ) X
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to a temporary table more than once in the same query.

Extracted from here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html

Answer (score 0):

If you weren't using a temporary table, you'd have gotten error 1093 instead.
The people on [Mysql 5.0 Subquery Errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-errors.html) imply that you have to break it up into two statements, such as:

```
SET @minRowNo = (SELECT MIN(RowNo) FROM _temptable WHERE Status = 'Deleted');
DELETE FROM _temptable WHERE RowNo > @minRowNo;
```

Though I do wonder at what it is you're trying to do by deleting all rows higher than the first row deleted, leaving the deleted row intact...